# Firemonkey android platform block emulators

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

i am trying to disable any access to my app from virtual devices some emulators like  [Blustacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) and [memuplay](http://www.memuplay.com/) , any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

And also virtualbox (yea android can run in virtualbox, it's easy like this) ... and if you can run your mac in virtualbox and apple can not detect it, i guess you will be not better than apple (ok, they are not very smart but they have much more engineer than you), so the simple answer to your question :

**you can not**